# How force unwrapping works in function parameters in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, nullable

I have one function in `Swift` like,

```
func getValue(param: String!) -> String {
    //access param
    //return a string
}
```

call is like,

```
let retVal = getValue(param: nil)
```

I expected that the param will try to force unwrap while taking into the function parameters and get crashed. But the code did not crash. Can anyone let me know **what am I missing?**

What will be different in case of the signature,

```
func getValue(param: String?) -> String
```

Comment: It's strongly discouraged to declare a function parameter as implicit unwrapped optional in a pure Swift environment. If you need an optional, declare a (regular) optional.

Comment: @vadian whats the reason behind that discouragement?

Comment: From the documentation: *Implicitly unwrapped optionals are useful when an optional’s value is confirmed to exist immediately after the optional is first defined and can definitely be assumed to exist at every point thereafter*. That's not valid for parameters. And if you are going to pass `nil` you certainly mean a regular optional. IUO parameters are only (enforced) useful for Objective-C interoperability.

Comment: @vadian got your point, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `!` means the param will hold String value or `nil`. So when you assign `nil` to `!` it is not supposed to crash. 
But when you try to access that value, it will crash.

This modification in your code will cause a crash as we are trying to access the value inside the variable which is `nil`.

```
func getValue(param: String!) -> String {
    if param.isEmpty {
        return ""
    }
    return ""
}

let retVal = getValue(param: nil)
```

Another example:

```
var string: String!
string = nil //This will not crash, but after this line if you try to access or perform any operation on it, it will
```

Now about this`func getValue(param: String?)` :

In this scenario the the `param` will be `optional type` unlike in the above scenario. So here you will have to unwrap it.

Answer (score 2):

Implicitly unwrapped optional (or IUO) may still contain `nil` as a value! In case of IUO you will get a crash only when you call any method/variable on it (e.g. `param.count`) OR when you assign it to a NON-Optional variable which will **led to force unwrapping operation**:

```
var param: String! = nil
var nonOptionalStr: String = param //<- Crash because it will try to force-unwrap param
```

Another example of a crash:

```
func foo(param: String!) -> String {
    return param //<- Crash! As return type is non-optional String it will try to force unwrap the param.
}
```

**On the other hand** IUOs (as well as Optionals) are also of type `Any` so if you pass a `String!` containing nil to a method which expects `Any` it will not crash because there will be no force-unwrapping operation as `Any?` can be easily cast to `Any` .

```
let str: String! = nil
print(str) //<-  No Crash! Becaise print accepts Any, so there will be no force-unwrapping
//Output: nil
```

Another example with type `Any`:

```
var a: Any? = nil
var b: Any = a //<- No Crash! As (Any?) is kind of (Any), though you will get a warning from compiler: Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to 'Any'
print(b)
//Output: nil
```